# How to turn off OneDrive's "Camera roll bonus" or folder auto-generation?

Tags: onedrive, photos, uploading

I have two WP devices (Lumia 535 and Lumia 735), on which I'm using OneDrive. For the second phone I have just the "basic" plan of 15 GB, while for first one I have a "Camera Roll bonus" in addition and 30 GB total space.

[image]

Even though I'm not using this feature (I have Settings > photo+camera > OneDrive > Auto-upload: off and none of the photos are actually auto-uploaded to my OneDrive), I can clearly see "*Camera roll bonus*" item in my OneDrive's configuration (when accessing OneDrive settings through webpage) and from time to time (I'd say once per 2-3 days) I can clearly see, that OneDrive is recreating folders for Documents and Photos in root of my OneDrive folder (even though I keep deleting them).

Does anyone know, why Lumia 535 / OneDrive is recreating these folders, even if auto-upload features are turned off? And is there any way to prevent this behavior?

**Additional info**: I've been using this particular OneDrive account for only this Lumia 535 device, but I have made up a total factory reset of the phone. Right after that, I have noticed, that my OneDrive keeps (in *Device backups* section) backups of two different phones -- one constantly and recently being updated / refresh and second one, that was updated for the last time in the day, when I performed device factory reset. I have deleted that obsolete "old" backup, but this caused me to think, if "wako" settings and additional storage bonus in OneDrive does not come from that old "before factory reset" copy of Windows, where I could have photo auto-upload enabled and Camera Roll bonus awarded. Does this sound like something reasonable? If yes, then it seems, that there will be now way to change this. But, then, why actual copy of OneDrive is keep recreating these folders, even though actual photo auto-upload is turned of?

Comment: This question should possible be moved to the [Web Applications SE](http://webapps.stackexchange.com), as it's about OneDrive rather than Windows Phone.

Comment: No, you're not right. This question is 100% about Windows Phone, as you can enable "Camera Roll" only on this phone. There is no switch or checkbox in OneDrive's web panel, because you can't enable this bonus, if you don't own a Lumia phone and don't register it with existing OneDrive account.

Comment: Not entirely true, the Camera Roll bonus is also available to Android and iOS users. Anyway, that was just a suggestion, nothing more :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what exactly is creating your Documents & Photos folders, but it is not the "Camera roll bonus". This bonus was added to your account when the automatic upload was active once and it is by design that this wont disappear after you deactivate it. 
[This bonus storage will disappear by January 31st 2016 if you do not object.](https://preview.onedrive.com/bonus/)

Also, this should have nothing to do with your backup files, as those are not in use in any way.

So what could be recreating your folders? This seems to be an ongoing issue, [several people are experiencing the same thing](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/forum/odwork-odfiles/why-does-onedrive-automatically-create-documents/3479b165-c96a-41a9-9870-41ebc7b0fc8e?page=1). Unfortunately I wasn't able to find a solution that seemed to work.

Perhaps the folder is being recreated by a connected Windows 8/10 PC, Office  or your phone. You could try narrowing it down using these after deleting the folders while having the other devices / tools shut down.

Comment: Accepting. Though you didn't answer directly to my question, you have provided me with a lot of interesting and useful information. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a windows 10 laptop signed in on your account, that will also try to backup pictures and such on onedrive. Perhaps that's related?

Comment: Nope, that's not an option in my case, but this might be valuable for others looking for solution to a similar problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Go to accounts (int Android settings), choose the 'OneDrive' and click on the user (account). Uncheck the 'Synch Media Storage' option.
That's it.
Enjoy.